# ion-radio trying to display into one line

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm currently trying to display a ion-radio button into one line and not a 3 line text like my code shows right now. Tried already with different ion-row or `style="display: inline"` but nothing worked for me.

**Output**

[image: MY RESULT]

**Expected Output**

[image: EXPECTED]

This is actually my code:

```html
<ion-col col-2 text-center>
     <div radio-group [(ngModel)]="flag1" align="center">
      <span class="spanRadioContainer">
       <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="false"></ion-radio>
      </span>
      <span style="display: inline">Nega il proprio consenso</span>
     </div>
    </ion-col>
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that output to attain group the radio with ion-label and wrap in inside ion-item, and wrap the ion-item with [ion-grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/), and for the label and the radio button to line use ion-item as per describe from the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/)

This is what I formulated, I didnt check it but it will work, try that code

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="autoManufacturers">
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
  <ion-col col-6>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Cord</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="cord"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-6>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Duesenberg</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="duesenberg"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: it's almost good your answer, the only problem right now my radion button is over the text. output: https://imgur.com/a/5GbwpJ4

Comment: try to add style='float: right' on the ion-label, css will do good for that sorry im not good at css

Comment: last problem, need the radio button on the left and not on the right, output: https://gyazo.com/938156fdb70ebe6eb5f5cee49548c4b0

Comment: <ion-item>
    <ion-radio value="duesenberg"></ion-radio>
    <ion-label>Duesenberg</ion-label>
</ion-item>